# Partial derivative of a function their variables depend on each other

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

if    $z=F\left(x,y\right)$ and   $y$=$\phi \left(x\right)$

Then is it correct to say that $z$ is just a function of a single variable which is $x$ ?

and if we try to compute $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ it will be equal to $\frac{dz}{dx}$ because the function $z$ will be affected only by the variable $x$ and it's nonsense in computing $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ to treat $y$ as a constant because it changes as $x$ changes ?

Note:I watched the multivariable course presented by Herbert Gross by MIT and in the lecture of partial derivatives he emphasized that in order to do partial derivatives the variables of the function must be totally independent in order to compute it

Answer (score 2):

Your function $F$ is a function defined on some subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ mapping onto $\mathbb{R}$. $\frac{dF}{dx}$ tells us, how the function $F$ changes, when we change $x$ "just a bit". Since the set your function is defined on is open, we can always moove $x$ "just a bit", in both directions. The same holds true for y. Keep it mind that $F$ is a completely different function than $F(x,\phi(x))$. The latter is a curve, the argument can only move in one dimension, the first one is not.

For the "treating y as a constant part" it is important to keep in mind that y is not a free variable, we can not choose values for y, they are determined by $x$.

$\frac{d}{dx} F(x,\phi(x)) = DF(x,\phi(x)) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x,\phi(x))^t= F_1(x,\phi(x)) \cdot 1 + F_2x,\phi(x))\cdot \phi^{\prime}(x)$.

Comment: so this means that z is a function of a single variable which is x

Comment: Yes, that means $z$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: ''Keep it mind that $F$ is a completely different function than $F(x,ϕ(x))$. The latter is a curve, the argument can only move in one dimension, the first one is not.''

are you refering to the diffrence between $F(x,y)$ and $F(x,ϕ(x))$ the first one there nothing to indicate that $y$ and $x$ are denpendent on each other so we treat them as two independent variables but the second one is not ,am I right ??

Comment: is my last comment what you meant to say ?

Comment: Yes, they are independet, since $F$ is a function over the plane we can "moove" its arguments in 2 dimensions, where as we can only "move" in 1 dimension for the curve.

Comment: I got what you are saying 
$F(x,y)$ is a function of $2$ independent variables unless we say that $y$$=$$\phi(x)$ 
if we say that $y$$=$$\phi(x)$ then our original function become a function of a single variable which is $x$

Comment: Exactly, and this new functions only has 1 variable, thats why it does not make sense to differentiate for the second one.